# How do you add a min JS file into Wordpress to then call on using script tags on my theme?

Tags: javascript, wordpress

How do you add a minified JS file into Wordpress to then call on using src within script tags on my theme?? I'm trying to use this particleground effect on several sections of my website.

I'm using Divi as my theme and following the directions this guy on youtube showed how to do here. 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qo86UfR2qSA

But he used an external link

Since I have an SSL installed on my site it doesn't allow me to link it. I have to essentially add it to WP using FTP or something I think but I'm not too knowledgeable about this and I hear that adding JS to Wordpress can be risky and can corrupt your whole site. I'm afraid to mess up, does anybody know where one should add files like these? is it on the theme folder?

Answer (score 1):

you can simply add your js file using this function by placing it in functions.php file under themes folder in  your theme or child theme.

```
function add_custom_script() {
      wp_enqueue_script( 'myscript', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/myscript.min.js');
}  
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_custom_script' );
```

you can follow this to achieve it.